# While using background mode for location update app consuming too much mobile data usage in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, cllocation

I am contiguous hitting server API on background mode using location update. It is working well but taking too much mobile data on daily basis. Is there any way to save mobile data?

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
[self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
[self.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges]; 

  if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates:)])
  {
    [self.locationManager setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates:YES];
  }

  [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
         didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    [self invokeAPIWithTimerToUpdateUserLocationOnServer];  
}
```

Comment: Send fewer updates to the server. Either less frequently or only when the user has moved a certain distance.

Comment: change the desiredAccuracy